# Libreoffice sum function - total column amount calculation

Tags: sum, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Does anyone know if in libreoffice macros it is possible to replace cell value (here H19 with the code)

```
function new1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell()
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=SUM(H2:H19)');;
};
```

I want to sum the values in the column H from H2 to the last cell that has values
(I calculate the last cell address that has values as 'currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell()' before moving to the cell below where I want to calculate the total)

But I do not know how to replace H19 with currentCell so that the macro worked

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I will not give an answer to your question, because I did not recognize the syntax of the code - which language is it? But, probably, a hint will help you: if you use the [**R1C1**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-use-r1c1-formulae-in-calc-macros/31768/6?u=johnsun) syntax, then the `=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)` formula (from the second cell in this column to the cell one row higher) will allow you to calculate the amount, wherever the cell with the formula is located.